# How to add stylesheet to other (different from header.php) files in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am learning wordpress and when I add css classes to other files than header.php and I am accessing those in style.css that does not work.Can someone suggest me how to fix it?

I have included properly the style.css and I have checked that with inspect element.

Comment: Did you enqueue your styles.css in functions.php?

Comment: I used the bloginfo function to add the style.css file and I have checked that with inspect element .

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/style.css' ?>">

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you see the .css file in the dev-tools but it not contains the changes you made? Or you don't see the `link` tag at all?

Comment: I see the style.css file in the dev-tools but the changes are not shown.

Comment: The proper way to include external css and js files in a wordpress theme is to have it enqueued in your functions.php. Check that file out and you'll see a function where you can add your custom css and js files using wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style() functions.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Comment: How was it? Was it now working?

Comment: Have you trying to run without cache? Maybe you get the same style.css because of it. See [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40669/51725) answer.